# How can I test the convergence of an exponential series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The infinite sum is:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {1+2^n}{1+3^n} $$

Comment: I would suggest ratio test...

Answer (score 3):

You have $1+2^n < 2\cdot 2^n = 2^{n+1}, 1+3^n > 3^n \Rightarrow a_n = \dfrac{1+2^n}{1+3^n} < \dfrac{2^{n+1}}{3^n} = b_n$, and $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n < \infty$ since it is geometric, so the former series converges.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1 + 2^n}{1+3^n} < \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n + \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n\right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1 + 2^n}{1+3^n} < \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^{n+1}}{3^n} =2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$$ which is convergent since it is a geometric series with common ratio $|r|<1$.

Hence by comparison test, convergence of the series is proved.